How to call a device function in another DLL in CUDA kernel
I have a DLL with an exported device function, and I am trying to write an executable that will call into that function in parallel on the device. But I get a compiler error on the line with the kernel call, and the error goes away if I comment out the call to the DLL function. The file used to create the DLL is myfunc.cu:
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

__declspec(dllexport) __device__ double myfunc(double x) {
    return x * x;  // Example function: square the input
}

I build it with:
nvcc -shared -o myfunc.dll myfunc.cu

It does create the dll and lib files.
I then the program that will call into it, kernel.cu:
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

__device__ double myfunc(double x);

__global__ void kernel(double* a, double* c) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    c[idx] = myfunc(a[idx]);
}

int main() {
    // ... (Host code to allocate memory, initialize data, and launch the kernel)

    int num_elements = 10000;
    double* a_h, * c_h;
    double* a_d, * c_d;

    // Allocate memory on the host
    cudaMallocHost(&a_h, num_elements * sizeof(double));
    cudaMallocHost(&c_h, num_elements * sizeof(double));


    // Allocate memory on the device
    cudaMalloc(&a_d, num_elements * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc(&c_d, num_elements * sizeof(double));

    // Copy data from host to device
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a_h, num_elements * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    // Launch the kernel
    kernel <<<10, 1024 >>> (a_d, c_d);

    // Copy results from device to host
    cudaMemcpy(c_h, c_d, num_elements * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // ... (Host code to use the results)

    // Free memory
    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(c_d);
    cudaFreeHost(a_h);
    cudaFreeHost(c_h);

    return 0;
}

I built this in Visual Studio 2022 in a project that started at the default for CUDA runtime, and added myfunc.lib to the linker inputs.
On the line
kernel <<<10, 1024 >>> (a_d, c_d);

I get the error "expected an expression" with a red squiggle underneath the third <. When I comment out
c[idx] = myfunc(a[idx]);

It builds fine.
What is the right way to do this?

It can't be done.  Device code linking is not possible across the DLL (or linux .so shared) interface.  Device code linking is possible across a static library interface.  I think this is probably a duplicate.

Actually in the interim I had one idea to try and it seems to have gotten rid of the error, which is to move the kernel function into the DLL and replaced the function with just the prototype.  I haven't tested it to see if there are other problems, but maybe it will work after all.

Yes, moving the kernel function into the DLL would eliminate the need for a device link across the DLL boundary.  That does not answer the question posed in the title, however: "How to call a device function in another DLL in CUDA kernel"

I looked at the "not possible" and "duplicate" links and I think this case is a bit different, or nvcc was upgraded since it was written. That's because with the kernel in the DLL I am able to compile and link with no issues, whereas those links seem to indicate the linking won't work. That said, while I can link, when I run it doesn't get into the kernel, silently skipping it. At least that it how it seems since the output is all 0 and print statements inside the kernel and myfunc never make it to the console. So that is the current problem...

Once you put the kernel in the DLL, wrap it in an ordinary C++ calling wrapper function.  That will work.  And regarding your other comments, it's not clear you understand the concept of device linking.  The other posts are referring to device linking.  When you move the kernel inside the DLL, a device link is no longer needed. So they don't apply to that case, nor does your original question.  But its no surprise that the link does not fail when you move the kernel into the same DLL that holds the __device__ function being called.

After wrapping it in an ordinary C++ function (does that mean no device or host?) then in the main program is it still kicked off with <<<>>> or called directly like an ordinary C++ function?

called directly like an ordinary C++ function.  kernel: __global__ void k(...){...};, wrapper: void wrapper(int blocks, int threads, ...){k<<<blocks, threads>>>(...);}  at the call point: wrapper(blocks, threads, ...);  kernel and wrapper in your DLL.  call point in your main function.

Wow that worked! Thanks so much!
